# Salesforce CPQ API to create Quote and Quote Line items facing issue with calculation

Tags: cpq, cpq-api

Using Salesforce CPQ API to create Quote and Quote Line items.
Records are created, but on Quote line items facing below error

> Before you can create an order, generate a document, or contract an opportunity, calculate this

Followed below Reference Links but was not helpful in resolving the error -

1. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000316738&type=1
2. https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002C7ISQA0&title=quote-lines-created-from-cpq-api-does-not-sync-to-opportunity

Due to this not able to generate Order/Order items.
Is there any way to invoke Calculator API through Apex code(automation)? Facing exception - FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: Order Products must have a Unit Price

Also verified by creating Price Rule or by creating new field and including it in fields set to initiate recalculation but it it not help.